# Display RSS Feeds on Salesforce Home Page

Tags: home-page-component

Im trying to display RSS feeds (link- http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_markets.rss) on Home Page. I generated the JavaScript code from http://feed2js.org/index.php?s=build and added the Home Page component by checking "Show HTML' and further added on Home Page layout, but it didnt showed the required RSS feed on Home Page. 
Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When copying the JavaScript code over make sure that you paste into the box with the Show HTML checked and leave it checked when you Save. Also make sure not to try and adjust the code (i.e. eliminationg spaces etc). Just paste as is. u will get code for sure i tried now

Comment: @SalesforceLearner If you feel this response answered your question, please mark this answer as  correct.